# How to flip flop with dplyr rows and columns positions

Tags: r, dplyr, flextable

This output of flextable function obtained with `as_grouped_data()` function.

```
df = structure(list(variable = c("something", NA, NA, NA), var = c(NA, "(Intercept)", "mutate1", "variable"), estimate = c(NA, 3.64770410229416, -0.230158472032055, -0.000692974348090823),  std.error = c(NA, 0.88, 0.0831, 0.9315), statistic = c(NA, 0.1933, -0.5458, -0.613), df = c(NA, 67.03, 53.27, 58.285), p.value = c(NA, "<0.001", "0.80", "0.87")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("grouped_data", "data.frame"))
```

which gives something like:

```
   variable         var      estimate std.error statistic     df p.value
1 something        <NA>            NA        NA        NA     NA    <NA>
2      <NA> (Intercept)  3.6477041023    0.8800    0.1933 67.030  <0.001
3      <NA>     mutate1 -0.2301584720    0.0831   -0.5458 53.270    0.80
4      <NA>    variable -0.0006929743    0.9315   -0.6130 58.285    0.87
```

Since I am working with flextable what that it is possible to get is:

```
df %>% flextable %>% colformat_double(j = c('estimate','std.error', 'statistic','df'))
```

[image]

I know that it can be considered as a piece of dataframe and I would like to do before converting it as a table, are modifications so as I could get finally with this results, possibly with dplyr

```
       variable        
       something   NA            NA         NA        NA  NA
       var          estimate      std.error  statistic df  p.value

        (Intercept)  3.6477041023    0.8800    0.1933 67.030  <0.001
        mutate1    -0.2301584720    0.0831   -0.5458 53.270    0.80
        variable   -0.0006929743    0.9315   -0.6130 58.285    0.87
```

Thus the final table that I would like to get is

```
     variable      NA.       NA        NA      NA      NA
1   something     <NA>      <NA>      <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
2         var estimate std.error statistic      df p.value
3 (Intercept)      3.6       0.9       0.2      67  <0.001
4      mutate     -0.2       0.1      -0.5    53.3     0.8
5    variable     -0.2       0.9       0.6    53.3    0.87
```

which as flextable show return

[image]

That just for the sake of getting the idea contains columns with X dotted and numbered NA, while those column should be in blank. Is that possible to adjust the dataframe with dplyr as I would wish.

Comment: Could you clean up the first code chunk, and then use the words above it to describe what it is?  Perhaps you are looking to have rownames and colnames for your dataframes instead of mixed variable types?

Comment: done. Hope that this will help to figure out

Comment: Not sure what your are looking for. Maybe using `broom::tidy()` gives you something you might want?

Comment: `as_grouped_data()` is supposed to work with `as_flextable()`, not `flextable()` although it can work. But it's not clear to me what you are expecting - it seems you only have one group, so `as_grouped_data()` have little interest here. I understand you are starting from a model, can you show what you'd like to have in the end?

Comment: also, not sure how you get the df object, it looks like some attributes are missing ($groups, and $columns)

Comment: @David Gohel I am not sure either as to what you would need. I think that there is all in the small reprex

Comment: do you want to add rows above a model summary in a flextable?

Comment: if it is not possible directly in flextable, I would at least do that with regular data wrangling with dplyr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also it does not answer the dplyr question, I think it can help you to do what you want. It answers the need to add rows above a model summary in a flextable:

```
library(flextable)
options(show.signif.stars = FALSE)
dat <- attitude
dat$high.rating <- (dat$rating > 70)
probit.model <- glm(high.rating ~ learning + critical +
                      advance, data = dat, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

ft <- as_flextable(probit.model) |> 
  delete_part(part = "footer") |> 
  add_header_lines(values = c("variable", "something")) |> 
  theme_booktabs()

ft
```

[image]

A more complete demonstration that shows how to add rows in header or in body:

```
ft <- as_flextable(probit.model) |> 
  delete_part(part = "footer") |> 
  add_header_row(values = c("on 2 columns", "on 3 columns"), colwidths = c(2, 3)) |> 
  add_header_lines(values = c("variable", "something")) |> 
  add_body_row(values = c("blah blah", "bleeh"), colwidths = c(3, 2), top = TRUE) |> 
  add_body_row(values = c("bleeh bleeh", "blah"), colwidths = c(3, 2), top = FALSE) |> 
  theme_vanilla() |> 
  color(i = ~ p.value > 0.05, color = "gray") |> 
  align(part = "header", i = 1:3, align = "left")
  
ft
```

[image]

Comment: It is a kind of counfusing. I used the as_grouped function since with my real data I have a kind of **something, something1, something2** (it is a grouping variable) that I wish to make as an header and for the sake to not leave any white space model values should go exactly there below

Comment: the add_header_* and add_body_* function will work with any flextable you produce. I can be more specific but for that I need the initial data and models (even if fake) so that I can show how to do with broom and `as_grouped_data()` :)

Comment: Letàs take for example down table in this website https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/reference/add_body_row.html. If I would like to just invert blah and bleeh rows with the header, How could be this done?

Comment: You can use `add_header_row` instead of `add_body_row`. https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/table-design.html#table-parts and https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/header-and-footer.html

Comment: I tried....but It does not work with me

Comment: What does not work? How can we help with 'it does not work'??

Comment: by using `add_header_row()` instead of `add_body_row()` in the example you mentioned, I get exactly what you are asking. It does work

Answer (score 3):

You want this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  fill(variable, .direction = "down") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(var)) %>%                 
  select(-1)
```

output:

```
          var      estimate std.error statistic     df p.value
1 (Intercept)  3.6477041023    0.8800    0.1933 67.030  <0.001
2     mutate1 -0.2301584720    0.0831   -0.5458 53.270    0.80
3    variable -0.0006929743    0.9315   -0.6130 58.285    0.87
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case exaclty. If you looks to the way it should be it is slightly different